# Comparing two list of DataFrames and outputting the difference only (using loops)

Tags: excel, pandas, loops, for-loop, compare

**UPDATE 2:**

Following Ouyang Ze's advice in the comments. I added float as my data type when reading in the list of Excel files. Additionally, I used `df.info()` to make sure my data types were indeed matching.

```
# Read in data from list of XLSX files and create a list of DataFrames
list_banks2 = [pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='Total ALL',skiprows=16, nrows=360, usecols='E:AR', dtype='float') for filename in all_filenames2]
```

[image]

**Spyder IDE variable explorer for DataFrame 2:**

[image]

**Same DataFrame values copy and pasted into Excel:**
Here the blue colored values should be rounded so it would match. The yellow colored values are what is confusing me. Even when I copy it into Excel it shows there is no difference in value, index, and data type. The red colored values should show. As such, rather than a (26,2) dataframe being outputted, there should only be a (3,2) dataframe with only three different values in the 2 dataframe comparison. Any ideas?

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

I believe the problem lies in the fact that my 2 dataframes values are different by 0.00000001 to 0.000000000000000001 which is causing it to show as different when I use my formula to compare 2 dataframes. Since I am using a loop to manipulate my dataframes, I cannot seem to be able to round my values to 2 or 3 significant digits. I have tried the following methods:

```
# Method 1:
for banks in list_banks1:
    banks.drop([14], axis=1, inplace=True)
    banks.round(2)
    banks.index +=1

# Method 2:
for banks in list_banks1:
    banks.drop([14], axis=1, inplace=True)
    banks.apply(lambda x:round(x,2))
    banks.index +=1

# Method 3:
for banks in list_banks1:
    banks.drop([14], axis=1, inplace=True)
    banks.round(2).astype(int)
    banks.index +=1

# Method 4:
for banks in list_banks1:
    banks.drop([14], axis=1, inplace=True)
    banks.round(2).astype(float)
    banks.index +=1
```

However, when I explore my variables in the Spyder IDE, I find that my dataframes have not been rounded to 2 significant digits. While it shows as 2 significant digits in the IDE, when I copy and paste the values into an Excel cell, it still shows the original value. As such, I thought I should be rounding the values from my list of dataframes, but I believe I cannot do that and will receive an error.

**QUESTION:**

I am working on a small task/project where I loop through two directories (one being a parent directory) and creating a list of DataFrames from the list of Excel (.xlsx) files.

```
## Recursive find all files in named directory and create list of files with XLSX extension
    os.chdir(input_drc1)
    extension = 'xlsx'
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('0*.{}'.format(extension))]
    list_banks = ["000","002","004","005","015","017","019","021","024","029","030","032","033","034","038","039"]

## Recursive find all files in named directory and create list of files with XLSX extension
os.chdir(input_drc2)
extension = 'xlsx'
all_filenames2 = [i for i in glob.glob('0*.{}'.format(extension))]
```

I then looped through the list of DataFrames to manipulate some data (dropped a column, rounded the values to 1 sig.fig, and increased the index by 1).

```
## Read in data from list of XLSX files
list_banks1 = [pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='Total (except non-resident)',skiprows=16, nrows=360, usecols='E:AR') for filename in all_filenames]

## Drop column 14 from all DataFrames in list of DataFrames
for banks in list_banks1:
    banks.drop([14], axis=1, inplace=True)
    banks.round(1)
    banks.index +=1
    # banks.apply(lambda x: pd.Series.round(x,1))

## Drop column 14 from all DataFrames in list of DataFrames
for banks in list_banks2:
    banks.drop([14], axis=1, inplace=True)
    banks.round(1)
    banks.index +=1
    # banks.apply(lambda x: pd.Series.round(x,1))
```

Ideally, my next step was to loop through the list of DataFrames from one directory and compare it to the list of DataFrames from the other directory. Unfortunately, I could not figure out if I could create a loop for this situation, so I created a loop to name each unique DataFrame for comparison purposes.

```
## Create unique DataFrames for each DataFrame in list
for i in range(0,len(list_banks)):
    globals()[f'df{list_banks[i]}LL'] = list_banks1[i]

## Create unique DataFrames for each DataFrame in list
for i in range(0,len(list_banks)):
    globals()[f'df{list_banks[i]}LC'] = list_banks2[i]
```

However, when I use the formula `def diff_pd`, I still get an output with equal values as seen in the picture below. The id column represents my row number and the col column represents my column number used in the original Excel files.

```
## Compare LL and LC dataframes and output differences only. 
check_df000 = diff_pd(df000LC,df000LL)
check_df002 = diff_pd(df002LC,df002LL)
check_df002 = check_df002.sort_values(by=["col"], inplace=True)
```

I believe my formula is working since it outputs less values than the total values in the Excel files, but it shows some that I believe have a different sig.fig. I tried rounding to no avail. I also tried pandas `df.compare` function but it is not the result I desired. I just want differences between the each pair of DataFrames from two separate directories to show with their column and row numbers. Ideally, without creating 24 unqiue DataFrames but just using two list of DataFrames instead.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, since I am a novice in this, and trying to learn, any guidance on cleaning up my code and streamlining it would be amazing.

[image]

```
## Import necessary modules
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import xlwings as xw
from datetime import date, datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

## Formula to compare two dataframes for differences (accounts for NaN values)
def diff_pd(df1, df2):
    """Identify differences between two pandas DataFrames"""
    assert (df1.columns == df2.columns).all(), \
        "DataFrame column names are different"
    if any(df1.dtypes != df2.dtypes):
        "Data Types are different, trying to convert"
        df2 = df2.astype(df1.dtypes)
    if df1.equals(df2):
        return None
    else:
        # need to account for np.nan != np.nan returning True
        diff_mask = (df1 != df2) & ~(df1.isnull() & df2.isnull())
        ne_stacked = diff_mask.stack()
        changed = ne_stacked[ne_stacked]
        changed.index.names = ['id', 'col']
        difference_locations = np.where(diff_mask)
        changed_from = df1.values[difference_locations]
        changed_to = df2.values[difference_locations]
        return pd.DataFrame({'from': changed_from, 'to': changed_to},
                            index=changed.index)

## Variables
## Subtracted a month to match report release month. 
input_date = datetime.now()
output_date1 = input_date-relativedelta(months=+1)
output_date2 = input_date-relativedelta(months=+2)
output_date3 = input_date-relativedelta(months=+13)

reportingCurrMonth = str(int(output_date1.strftime("%m"))).zfill(2)
reportingLastMonth = str(int(output_date2.strftime("%m"))).zfill(2)
reportingCurrYear = str(int(output_date1.strftime("%Y")))
reportingCurrYear2 = str(int(output_date1.strftime("%y")))
reportingLastYear = str(int(output_date3.strftime("%Y")))
reportingLastYear2 = str(int(output_date3.strftime("%y")))

## File Directory & Files
input_drc = r"D:/BOM/Work Files/3. Monthly Rural-Area Credit Report/"
input_drc1 = input_drc+reportingCurrYear+"/zeelt"+reportingCurrYear2+"-m"+reportingCurrMonth
input_drc2 = input_drc+reportingCurrYear+"/zeelt"+reportingCurrYear2+"-m"+reportingLastMonth

#Intialize xlwing App and hide processes
app = xw.App(visible=False)
app.display_alerts=False

## Recursive find all files in named directory and create list of files with XLSX extension
os.chdir(input_drc1)
extension = 'xlsx'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('0*.{}'.format(extension))]
list_banks = ["000","002","004","005","015","017","019","021","024","029","030","032","033","034","038","039"]

## Read in data from list of XLSX files
list_banks1 = [pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='Total (except non-resident)',skiprows=16, nrows=360, usecols='E:AR') for filename in all_filenames]

## Drop column 14 from all DataFrames in list of DataFrames
for banks in list_banks1:
    banks.drop([14], axis=1, inplace=True)
    banks.round(1)
    banks.index +=1
    # banks.apply(lambda x: pd.Series.round(x,1))
    
## Create unique DataFrames for each DataFrame in list
for i in range(0,len(list_banks)):
    globals()[f'df{list_banks[i]}LL'] = list_banks1[i]
   

## Recursive find all files in named directory and create list of files with XLSX extension
os.chdir(input_drc2)
extension = 'xlsx'
all_filenames2 = [i for i in glob.glob('0*.{}'.format(extension))]

## Read in data from list of XLSX files and create a list of DataFrames
list_banks2 = [pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='Total ALL',skiprows=16, nrows=360, usecols='E:AR') for filename in all_filenames2]

## Drop column 14 from all DataFrames in list of DataFrames
for banks in list_banks2:
    banks.drop([14], axis=1, inplace=True)
    banks.round(1)
    banks.index +=1
    # banks.apply(lambda x: pd.Series.round(x,1))

## Create unique DataFrames for each DataFrame in list
for i in range(0,len(list_banks)):
    globals()[f'df{list_banks[i]}LC'] = list_banks2[i]

## Compare LL and LC dataframes and output differences only. 
check_df000 = diff_pd(df000LC,df000LL)
check_df002 = diff_pd(df002LC,df002LL)
check_df002 = check_df002.sort_values(by=["col"], inplace=True)

# Kill xlwing processes to close all Excel files
app.kill()
```

Comment: your intuition is right-- make a function for this.  I'd say make sth like this as simple as possible.  don't use the else in diff_pd, not needed.  forget multiindexing here, also seems unnecessary.  If u want to do sth like this, try (df1 != df2).sum() >0 as the way to choose what columns are off.  When you get further down the roaad of the fundamentals, take a look at [engarde](https://engarde.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#checks) and [great-expectations](https://greatexpectations.io/), which may be useful libraries in this case.

Comment: @OuyangZe. Thank you for your response. I thought creating a function would be the easiest and most applicable method for this issue. I don't want to do a merge to compare the two dataframes. The pandas compare function also does not yield the result I want. Regardless, whatever method I choose to use I keep getting stuck on one part. I get an output that there is a difference between the two values from the two dataframes. When I manually check the 2 Excel files, the two values are same exactly, yet when I compare the two using Python I keep getting the value as different. Any ideas?

Comment: I think i get it... 1st, the function you've created is exactly the same as this -- `lambda df1, df2: df1.compare(df2, align_axis=0)` as described in the docs for pd.Dataframe.compare.  2nd, if there's a value failing this comparison it could be many things.. for example, excel has a default number of values it will render for a number -- I ran into that once looking at id numbers that exceeded this limit, looked equal in excel, actually were different.  other potential issue is how pandas is reading the data, so u can be more specific on the `pd.read_excel` moment, including encoding + dtypes